# Reusable Function in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

We have 'chunks' of identical formulas in different parts of our app.  In light of PA lacking actual named functions, are there any workarounds that would allow us to reuse a function/formula to prevent duplication of 'code' (i.e. formula)?

Comment: Don’t get me started on how big of an omission this is, in terms of doing any level of professional/enterprise scale development with Canvas Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a hidden button or other selectable item and then assign the formula to this button. Whenever you need to rerun the formula, instead of recreating the formula, use Select(Button1).

For instance, if you need to have a formula that adds to a collection:

1. Add a button called Button1.

   1. Set the Visible property to False
   2. Set the OnSelect property to something like `Collect(YourCollection,"A Value")`
2. Anywhere that needs to call this function set the OnSelect property to `Select(Button1)`

If you need to set a dynamic value to this collection, you can set a context variable first

1. Change the OnSelect property for Button1 to `Collect(YourCollection,yourVariable)`
2. Set the OnSelect property of you control to `UpdateContext({yourVariable,"A Value"});Select(Button1)`

Of course this is a very simple example and can be expanded upon.

Of course you can also go the Power Automate route, calling a Flow from within your PowerApp control to do your work, but that may require additional licensing if you do complex work within the Flow and return values then have to be parsed.

Here's hoping Microsoft eventually allows us to create custom functions that can be called within PowerApps.

Comment: Thank you for this example of an approach -- I'll give it a try!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I can't use Select() across screens.  Is there a workaround to selecting a button on a different screen?

Comment: I was able to apply Robbert's approach to a hidden instance of a custom component in my app.  I simply put the formula that I wanted to reuse into the components OnReset handler and then I could initiate the formula from anywhere in my app by calling Reset(myCustomComponent).  Seems to work so far, thanks!  Since components also have custom Input and Output properties, these could also be leveraged to provide some degree of encapsulation -- for PowerApps anyways.

Comment: @EngineRoom, that's a great solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: One other note on this technique -- it appears that the custom component will not have access to global variables in the app but it can access collections (from what I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

This has just been announced, which allows makers to create user-defined formulas using components: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enhanced-component-properties/.

Here's an example from the blog post:

> We can use property parameters in input and output properties too.  A good example of this would would be a math utilities library.  We don’t currently offer Excel’s **RandBetween** function in Power Apps.  But, we can recreate it using the **Rand** function that we do support.
>
> Let’s start by creating a new **MathUtils** component with a **RandBetween** custom property of property type **Output** and Data type **Number**:
>
> [image: New property]
>
> We’ll add two parameters to this property for the range.  Excel names these parameters **Bottom** and **Top**, of type Number.  These are both required parameters in Excel.
>
> [image: Bottom parameter]
>
> And with the same thing done for **Top**:
>
> [image: Top parameter]
>
> Within the component, we’ll define the formula for calculating **RandBetween** based on these parameters:
>
> ```
> If( Top >= Bottom, 
>     Round( Rand() * (Top - Bottom) + Bottom, 0 ),
>     Blank()
> )
> ```
>
> [image: Expression parameter]
>
> Now we can call it like a function from within our app.  We will need to create an instance of this component in our app, with the default name **MathUtils_1**.  Here two slider controls are used as input and the result is shown in a label control:
>
> [image: Using function]